# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.example.weshop:drawable/splash_background with resource ID #0x7f070090

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I was not able to launch the splash activity. I have used the theme method to set splash screen. But it is showing resource not found exception.

log statements

```
2021-12-21 00:03:31.091 28694-28694/com.example.weshop E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.weshop, PID: 28694
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.weshop/com.example.weshop.SplashScreenActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.example.weshop:drawable/splash_background with resource ID #0x7f070090
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2932)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3010)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1707)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6759)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:875)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.example.weshop:drawable/splash_background with resource ID #0x7f070090
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/splash_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f070090
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:980)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:769)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:913)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:855)
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:605)
        at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat$Api21Impl.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:864)
        at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:483)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:148)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:480)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:93)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.attachToWindow(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:803)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureWindow(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:779)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:506)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity$2.onContextAvailable(AppCompatActivity.java:131)
        at androidx.activity.contextaware.ContextAwareHelper.dispatchOnContextAvailable(ContextAwareHelper.java:99)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreate(ComponentActivity.java:322)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:273)
        at com.example.weshop.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:12)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7147)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7138)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2885)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3010)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1707)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6759)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:875)
     Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #6: <bitmap> requires a valid 'src' attribute
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.updateStateFromTypedArray(BitmapDrawable.java:823)
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.inflate(BitmapDrawable.java:754)
2021-12-21 00:03:31.093 28694-28694/com.example.weshop E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:142)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1295)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1284)
        at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflateLayers(LayerDrawable.java:279)
        at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:194)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:142)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1295)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1254)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:958)
            ... 30 more
x
```

build.gradle app

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.weshop"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

drawable/splash_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/white"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Weshop" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background</item>
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.weshop">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Weshop">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

since I am using the api32 there might be some issue with vector supports but I cant figure it out. please help me i will be greatful

SplashScreenActivity.java

```
package com.example.weshop;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to check your android:src="@drawable/logo image, must be a png in the drawable folder

Comment: @ManueMato yes i have logo.xml. so api 32 doesnt support vector drawables?? how can i use vector drawables ??